# Access to Site.Master objects from an asp.net file

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp page that is using Site.Master.

I put a link in Site.Master, and master included default.aspx. How can I access link attribute in asp file?

in Site.Master :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx" 
                    Target="_blank">Register</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this is to do something along the lines of:

```
HyperLink link =  this.Master.FindControl("id_of_the_control_you_are_looking_for") as HyperLink;
```

But note thet `FindControl` is not recursive, so you'll need to first find the control that holds the hyperlink you are looking for and then do another `FindControl` on this container using the id of the hyperlink you need.

Comment: Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\inetpub\wwwroot\School\Default.aspx.cs 12 26 C:\...\School\

Comment: I am sure you forgot to add `as HyperLink;` Check my answer again and scroll all the way to the right.

Comment: Login login2 = this.Master.FindControl("Login1") as Login;
            login2.Visible = false; Why it doesnt Work ?!

Comment: I told you FindControl is not recursive. Most likely "Login1" is inside another control (a Panel for example)

Comment: Then you need to do this: `this.FindControl("PanelContainingLoginControl").FindControl("Login1").Visible=false;` Follow?

Comment: it is not in panel !!!! condition is like hyperlink . Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11745/discussion-between-moslem7026-and-icarus)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is add a MasterType directive to your content page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.Default" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

Now you can access every *public* item from your MasterPage in your content page.

Let's say your MasterPage has this in its codebehind:

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then do this in your content page:

```
public partial class Default
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.Name = "Bobby";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean with "link attribute" in your question, but if you mean an HyperLink, here's how you can do this:

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public HyperLink SharedHyperLink { get { return myHyperLink; } }
}

public partial class Default
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.SharedHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "/Contact.aspx";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have a link somewhere inside your Master page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="mylink" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="test" />
```

Then in the code behind of the child page you could fetch it like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var link = FindControlRecursive(Master, "mylink") as LinkButton;
        if (link != null)
        {
            var css = link.CssClass;
            // TODO: do something with the link
        }
    }

    private static Control FindControlRecursive(Control control, string id)
    {
        if (control.ID == id)
        {
            return control;
        }

        foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
        {
            var foundCtrl = FindControlRecursive(ctrl, id);
            if (foundCtrl != null)
            {
                return foundCtrl;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```